# EB that handle websockets with the Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, socket.io

My goal is to create an EB with an Application Load Balancer to use websockets (with socket.io).

I read that it is possible with the "application load balancer" but I can't make it work.

I wrote some NodeJS code that build an HTTP server that listen on port 8081 and answer a 200, and a socket.io server that listen on the port 3000 to accept connections.

Here are the stepped i followed:

First, I ran eb  --elb-type application

Then, I created 2 Target Groups, one for the 8081 port (used for HTTP), and another one for the 3000 port (used fo ws), here are screenshots of these groups:[image: Group HTTP] [image: Group WS]

As you can see, I attached to these both groups the EC2 created and managed by the EB.

Then, I configured the Application Load Balancer so it can use these groups:

[image: Load Balancer][image]

When I hit my EB URL, or the Application Load Balancer URL from my browser, I get a timeout. And it is the same thing for my ws connection... I don't see what I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to check:

a. A timeout most probably means the Security Group is not correctly setup. Go to EC2 - LB - Your LB - Description tab. Click on the security group that is listed there.
Check the in-bound rules on this, you need to have the relevant port open with either 0.0.0.0/0 as a source, if you plan to have this ALB open to the world. Or a relevant CIDR Block/SG based on your architecture.

b. Go to EC - LB - Target Groups - select your target groups, under the targets tab verify that your instances are coming up healthy.
If not ensure that you have correctly setup your health checks.

Comment: My security Group wasn't OK, it allowed all inboud protocols and ports but not for 0.0.0.0/0 !

My HTTP works now ! but i have an issue of Access-Control-Allow-Origin with my ws connection.

Thanks ! I am going to dig further